# What are the difference between TAG_DISCOVERED, NDEF_DISCOVERED and TECH_DISCOVERED with discovering NFC devices or tag in android?

Tags: android, android-manifest, nfc, intentfilter

What are the differences between `TAG_DISCOVERED`, `NDEF_DISCOVERED` and `TECH_DISCOVERED` while discovering NFC devices or tags in android?

Comment: Good question; many developers struggle with this. Nowadays, the official documentation contains an extensive explanation of this, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html#dispatching